# bootstrap container contents in the left side of the screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I have a container with a login form.

However, I want to align this form to the left side of the page.  However, using float left makes it look ugly and also makes the form input smaller, as you can see here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZGOjR

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
      <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" role="form" >
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-icon-lined btn-icon-round btn-icon-sm btn-default-light">

            </div>
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg input-round text-center" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" name="email" ng-required autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-icon-lined btn-icon-round btn-icon-sm btn-default-light">

            </div>
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg input-round text-center" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-round btn-block text-center">Log in</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I make it so the form input is to the left side without looking ugly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it the bootstrap way. You could add a column width to the form `<div class="form-container text-center col-xs-3">`

Here is your original example tidied up a bit http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXbKvN

Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid system so that everything is nicely laid out on the page. For more info have a look here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: Thanks.  What about having it like this on only >768px width, but on mobile it is in the middle?

Comment: You could do this `<div class="form-container text-center col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">` (also updated the codepen link)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: 350px;` to the `.form-container` class.

It can better, if you can upload your design. screenshot.